# Need assistance with jQuery posting data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So what I am trying to do is use a full calendar ajax call to get the event registered in the database.
When I try to do that, no error pops up, infact, the ajax call returns successful addition to the the database.

I tested the PDO query separately and it is working perfect, so kindly assist me with the ajax post, because that is what I have short listed the error to.

This is the ajax call in default.html.

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
    if (title) {
         var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
         var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
         console.log("Event Triggered");
         $.ajax({
                 url: 'add_events.php',
                 data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: 'text',
                success: function(json) {
                    alert('Added Successfully');
                 },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
         });
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
             title: title,
             start: start,
             end: end,
             url:url,
             allDay: allDay
        },
            true // make the event "stick"
        );
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

And this is the add_events.php (Kindly note that this has no error except that it is not receiving the post.)

```
  <?php
   // Values received via ajax

  $data = $_POST;
  $json_array["title"]=json_decode($data["title"], true);
  $json_array["start"]=json_decode($data["start"], true);
  $json_array["end"]=json_decode($data["end"], true);
  $json_array["url"]=json_decode($data["url"], true);


  $title =$json_array["title"];
  $start =$json_array["start"];
  $end = $json_array["end"];
  $url = $json_array["url"];
  // connection to the database
 try {
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', '....',    '.......');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
   exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }



  $sql  = "INSERT INTO "
  .   "`evenement` "
  . "SET "
  .   "`title`   = :title, "
  .   "`start`   = :start, " 
  .   "`end`     = :end, " 
  .   "`url`     = :url ";

     $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $result = $stmt->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end,  ':url'=>$url));
    if (!$result) {
        print_r($pdo->errorInfo());

    }   
?>
```

I see xhr GET request in the console log with post variables. They are just not going from the jQuery to php.

Any assistance how that could be achieved would be appreciated.

The JQuery Pop up after adding an event says :

PHP Error : Undefined Index (for all variables)

The variables set from jQuery are not passing to the php.

The Header of main file(default.html) looks like this :

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
 <link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
 <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
 <!--<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
 <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

The console is giving the following error :-
POST http://localhost/calendar/add_events.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is the error in the network tab :-
http://postimg.org/image/4k9ztzuep/

Based on the answer provided by `delighted` I was able to get the query working and resolving the jQuery error.

But the POST does not work :-
I say this because I changed all fields to allow NULL but than it does allow NULL and creates a NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL entry in the database.

Comment: Question 1: How are you seeing a GET request in the console when your ajax is a POST request ?

Comment: Regarding "Any assistance how that could be achieved would be appreciated." Use  $_POST

Comment: @DeepKakkar the OP is using $_POST....

Comment: I believe you should be using a JSON syntax to set your data.

Comment: @Aukhan
The JSON syntax makes the entire calendar dissapear

Comment: The important part to note first @UmarAftab was that did your undefined index error go away ?

Comment: Please attach a detailed screenshot of what your request looks like in your console. Maybe that can help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your images of the request, you need to set `dataType:'text',` in your `ajax` call.

Also, in your PHP, change your PDO to:

```
// "?"s here will get replaced with the array elements below
$sql = 'INSERT INTO  evenement ( title,start,end,url) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ? )';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($title, $start, $end, $url )); // these array elements will replace the above "?"s in this same order

// check for errors
if($stmt->errorCode() == 0) {
    $id = $db->lastInsertId(); // get the id form the inserted record, not really needed but I put it here to show you how

}
else {
    // had errors
    $errors = $stmt->errorInfo();
    print_r($errors);
}
```

Additionally,you should always encode your inputs when building your data string **especially since you are passing dates and a URL**.

Change your code to:

```
data: 'title='+ encodeURIComponent(title)+
      '&start='+ encodeURIComponent(start)+
      '&end='+ encodeURIComponent(end)+
      '&url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
```

#### Note, even if this doesn't solve your current issue, you should still implement this change ;)

Comment: +1 For this is the right way to send url parameters. The OP said he was seeing an `undefined index` error in his php script

Comment: Let me try this out !

Comment: Console Error :
POST http://localhost/calendar/add_events.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @UmarAftab can you open the console, go to the network tab, click on that request and take a screenshot of the request headers and form data please?

Comment: Ok , I just did and I will post the link right now because I cannot post images

Comment: @UmarAftab almost, but click on that red `add_events.php` we need to see the details

Comment: And the Preview says :
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\calendar\add_events.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: start in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\calendar\add_events.php on line 16
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: end in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\calendar\add_events.php on line 17
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\calendar\add_events.php on line 18

Comment: Its been over 2 weeks I am stuck on this..any ideas

Comment: The Request Payload says title = "asdasd"
That's exactly what I was entering

Comment: @UmarAftab Add `dataType : "text",` to your ajax call and try it again please

Comment: And please post a screenshot of that request, you should have `Form Data` not `Request Payload` like this:  http://i.imgur.com/SXZFRVr.png

Comment: Then why do I have Request Payload, how can I change that ?

Comment: I added the following :
             dataType:'text',
             cache: false,
        contentType : 'application/json',

Comment: Cool, glad you got sorted :)

Comment: @UmarAftab dont forget to close the question if it's resolved now )

Comment: But the issue is that it does not save to the database though, it does not pop up the error, and when I refresh the event is gone.

Comment: Is there anyway I can check where the data is and why it is not in the php $_POST ?

Comment: The data is now in the $_POST, you're not getting the undefined index error anymore right? See my edit above regarding your PDO, try that and let me know please

Comment: I still am getting the undefined index error but not via jQuery as that returns with a 200 OK. However, I am getting it from the php variables...

Comment: When you do, go to the request in the console again and this time show me the `Response` tab

Comment: This is what the response tab says :

`Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1048
    [2] => Column 'title' cannot be null
)`

Comment: Ok here is a breakthrough, the database query is being triggered, the post is not working, I say this because I changed all fields to allow NULL but than it does allow NULL and creates a NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL entry in the database.

Comment: Show me the Headers tab for that some request in the console

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/y03lq0fcf/ 

Interesting thing, as I allowed NULL in the database table, and I insert the name and URL with double quotes, they get saved and registered  but the time element does not, it stores as NULL so when I refresh, all the events disappear.
And the error is shown in the image, we are almost there, I can't tell you how much I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Do var_dump($_POST) at the top or your php script and tell me what I says in the response tab please

Comment: I changed the add_events.php file, check the question, I am doing a jason_decode thats why it was inputting....

Comment: You don't need any of that json stuff, what you showed before was right